# Python Tabs Fake or Real

Tags: python, character-encoding

Many tutorial suggest users to use tab with width of 4 while 4 is made using spaces not real tab character. Using real tab also it works so why do people suggest to use spaces of 4 rather than real tab ? I'm a python beginner confused ????

[UPDATE]
Thanks! I am now switching to spaces of 4.

Added following to my .vimrc
"Python

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*pyw set shiftwidth=4
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw set expandtab
fu Select_c_style()
    if search('^\t', 'n', 150)
        set shiftwidth=8
        set noexpandtab
    el 
        set shiftwidth=4
        set expandtab
    en
endf
```

For other case:

```
set noexpandtab                " tabs are tabs, not spaces
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tabs versus spaces in Python programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119562/tabs-versus-spaces-in-python-programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you allow a tab character into a file, you will end up in a situation with mixed tabs and spaces, and then you will start to get parsing errors. This gets worse when multiple people are working on a project, and have their spacing settings set different from each other.

PEP8 recommends "4 spaces": http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

And this recommendation is made with experience, dealing with the kinds of problems that mixing tabs and spaces in Python brings. Much, much better to save yourself the pain, and just use 4 spaces for your Python code.

Comment: I do not get situations with mixed tabs and spaces because my text editor has been properly instructed not to mix them. Tabs are not hard to use properly, given non-brain-dead editors, and the entire point is to allow people to "have their spacing settings different from each other" - to view the code with the amount of indentation that makes it most readable for them - without actually changing the text. I indent with tabs, in every programming language, and set them to 2 spaces because that's what looks right to me. But apparently this is all heresy.

Comment: I prefer a tabstop of 2 spaces too.

Answer (score 2):

The Python compiler considers the tab character to be equivalent to indentation of 8 spaces. You can use tabs if you like but mixing tabs and spaces will lead to tricky-to-debug errors, which is why sticking with spaces is recommended.

Comment: BTW, you should probably look into the `tabnanny` module if you think you might run into problems due to mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: Python 3 changes the rules.  Mixing of tabs and space in the same indentation is now prohibited and results in this error from the interpreter: `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can consider may be that if you don't have set up your editor to use `tabstop=4` (say, in VIM) your code lines will be longer and it will be inconvenient to read such a code. The only rule should be not to mix tabs and spaces, I think (I have seen code where the single indent was four spaces and the double indent was a tab. It was horrible.)

Comment: IIRC, Visual Studio will by default set a 4-space indent, but automatically replace sets of 8 spaces with tabs, while displaying them as 8 spaces wide. Maybe those aren't the default settings, but I've seen a lot of code formatted that way. It's disgraceful. I really don't understand why the proper use of tabs is apparently so difficult for so many people, to the point where they're advised against completely.

Comment: @Karl I prefer to use tabs, since everyone in the project can make her/his editor to display it as needed (2, 4, or the whole 8 spaces).

Comment: Or 3 or 5 or... I don't think I will ever understand those people, but I won't discriminate against them. :)

Answer (score 1):

Many, if not most editors will do an inline conversion of tabs to a user defined number of spaces. Set that to 4 and you are home free. The real pain comes when you are on a team that hasn't standardized on this idea of 4 spaces.